# Wicket, загрузка файла

Tags: веб-программирование, wicket

Здравствуйте, уважаемые знатоки `wicket`. Раньше загрузка файла для меня была легкой задачей при выборе файла клиентом и отправки формы я в методе `onSubmit` извлекал файл, записывал его в нужную директорию, но сейчас задача немного усложнилась. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при выборе клиентом файла и при нажатии кнопки отправки формы, файл сам извлекался и сохранялся в нужную мне директорию и все это без без переопределения метода `onSubmit`.

Comment: Конечно, можно. Можно даже сделать так, чтобы пользователю файл не нужно было выбирать. Необходимый файл сам бы сохранялся в нужную директорию.

Comment: я оценил ваш ответ капитан сарказм, но все же  есть ли  нормальные знатоки wicket?